# Debugger configuration in GoGland

Tags: debugging, curl, go, jetbrains-ide, goland

I want to debug my go application when I send request using curl command.

Currently my request is handled by the binary I have. 
What I want that when I send request using curl command request should be handled by the code I have not by the binary.

I did not find any documentation about it, only found this [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41592892/how-to-set-up-debugging-in-gogland)which is still unanswered.

@Zoyd did you found a way to configure it?

Answer (score 2):

I've made a short video of how debugging works in Gogland and how it should be configured: https://youtu.be/tT0Op-DYs4s.

In place of the Println you can have your usual api handler and then just run the curl command against your API as usual, as long as you run this with the debugging configuration.